# Camera does not open until I click back button - android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In my android application, when I clicked on the button first it should open the camera and once I capture an image it should redirects to a new activity.

**But what happens is, when I click on the button first it redirects to new activity and once I clicked the back button it opens the camera.**

I can't understand what's the problem in my code, seems like it's in well order.Any Help?

```
    public void onCameraButtonClicked()
    {

        camera_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
                        makingDirectory(dir);

                        storePicture(dir);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void makingDirectory(String dir)
    {
        File newdir = new File(dir);
        newdir.mkdirs();
    }

    public void storePicture(String dir)
    {
        boolean flag_storePicture = false;
        // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
        // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
        // and likewise.
        count++;
        String file = dir+count+".jpg";
        File newfile = new File(file);
        try
        {
            newfile.createNewFile();
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            flag_storePicture = true;
            Log.d("myApp", "Hiiiiii from inside");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }
        finally {
            Log.d("myApp", "Hiiiiii");
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent("com.example.lalinda.googlemap1.Camera");
            startActivity(camera_intent);
        }
    }
```

In my logcat I'm getting this message.

```
Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it clear to you as well , the issue is flow of control ,

inside try block , the `camera` app has been opened for you

```
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

then right after that `finally` gets executed

```
finally {
            Log.d("myApp", "Hiiiiii");
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent("com.example.lalinda.googlemap1.Camera");
            startActivity(camera_intent);
        }
```

and now you have your `googlemap1.Camera` activity over your camera app so hence if you press back you will find your camera app.

Solution : as per your requirements move your `finally` block code into `onActivityResult` along with an `if` condition to verify the image capture task completion. like

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){ // image captured successfully 
            //..code to start your other activity 
        Intent camera_intent = new Intent("com.example.lalinda.googlemap1.Camera");
        startActivity(camera_intent);
        }else{
           // ..  image capture failure , user pressed cancel etc
           }
    }
```